# Palindrome Checker using Stack in Java (Always returning false)

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying my hand at creating my own Stack class in Java. I'm not sure where my code is wrong, but if I enter an actual palindrome into my program console it always returns false. Where is my problem happening?

Here is my palindrome client file: (my stack.java class is accessible in the same program folder.)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

//declare both stacks
Stack<String> fwd = new Stack<String>();
Stack<String> rev = new Stack<String>();

//instance variables
String st1;
boolean palindrome = true;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a String and I will check if it is a palindrome: \n");

st1 = in.nextLine();

// Read the data in forward order into the Stack
for (int i =0; i < st1.length(); i++) {
  fwd.push(Character.toString(st1.charAt(i)));
}
// Read the same data in reverse order into another Stack
for (int j = st1.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
  rev.push(Character.toString(st1.charAt(j)));
}
System.out.println("The string you entered was: ");
System.out.println(fwd.display());
System.out.println(rev.display());
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Checking to see if " + st1 + " is a palindrome.");
System.out.println("/**********************************************");

//check fwd and rev against each other
while (!fwd.isEmpty() && !rev.isEmpty()) {  // make sure stack in not empty
  for (int i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++) {  // go through each element in the stack

     if (fwd.pop() == rev.pop()) //check if fwd pop and rev pop are the same
        palindrome = true;
     else
        palindrome = false;

  }//end for lop
}// end while loop

System.out.println(palindrome);


}// end main

}// end Palindrome
```

Here is my Stack.java file:

```
public class Stack<E> implements StackInterface<E> {

   //variables
   private ArrayList<E> data;
   private E element;


   //constructor
   public Stack() {

      data = new ArrayList<E>();
   }


   //stack methods
   public void push(E element) { //push new element into the stack

      data.add(element);
   }

   public E pop() { //pop the element from the top

      if (data.isEmpty()) //if stack is empty, throw exception
         throw new EmptyStackException("The stack is empty.");
      else //else, remove and return the element that is on top of the stack
         return data.remove(data.size()-1); 
   }

   public E peek() { //peek at the element on top of the stack without removing it

      if (data.isEmpty()) //if stack is empty, throw exception
         throw new EmptyStackException("The stack is empty.");
      else //else, return the element that is on top of the class
         return data.get(data.size()-1);   
   }

   public String display() { //display the elements in the stack in the form of a String

      if (data.isEmpty()) //if stack is empty, throw exception
         throw new EmptyStackException("The stack is empty");
      else //else, return elements as a String
         return data.toString();
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() { //check to see if the stack is empty

      if (data.size() == 0)
         return true;
      else
         return false;

   }

   public int size() { //retrurn the number of elements in the stack

      return data.size();

   }

}// end Stack class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: That moment when you think "today there will be no `==` vs `equals` questions!".

Comment: This is not the solution, but if you add to (!fwd.isEmpty() && !rev.isEmpty()) &&  palindrome , you save a little bit of runtime. Also after palindrome = false; you can call break, because you already know its no palindrom.

Comment: @Maroun Still familiarizing myself with the java language. Will not make that silly mistake again, now that I understand the difference!

Comment: @MagdaleneB. That's OK :) Everyone do mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (fwd.pop() == rev.pop())`  should be `if (fwd.pop().equals(rev.pop()))` since you're comparing content of two strings.

You should also `break` your while loop if you detect that it's not a palindrome, otherwise "test" would return `true`.

```
if (fwd.pop().equals(rev.pop())) //check if fwd pop and rev pop are the same
                palindrome = true;
             else {
                palindrome = false;
                break;
                 }
}
```

**Edit :**

As said in commment the for loop inside the while is actually useless.

Another option would be to create two stacks of `Characters` and now you can use `==` to compare them :

```
Stack<Character> fwd = new Stack<>();
Stack<Character> rev = new Stack<>();

/**/
for (int i =0; i < st1.length(); i++) {
    fwd.push(st1.charAt(i));
}
for (int j = st1.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    rev.push(st1.charAt(j));
}
while (!fwd.isEmpty() && !rev.isEmpty()) {  // make sure stack in not empty
        if (fwd.pop()==rev.pop()) //check if fwd pop and rev pop are the same
           palindrome = true;
        else {
           palindrome = false;
           break; //here break the while loop it's not a palindrom
        }
}// end while loop
```

Comment: just to add information, the for loop inside the while is not needed.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Still familiarizing myself with java in the form of fun little test projects like these. :)

Comment: @RamonBoza Thank you, I see what you mean and I took it out now.

Comment: Aha. I see. I tried making a char stack initially but when I got a compile error for making it like this: 
'code'Stack<char> fwd = new Stack<>(); 
I didn't try any further. Now I know how to define a Character Stack, thank you!

Comment: @MagdaleneB. Notify the break statement. It's very important, otherwise words like "test" would say that is a palindrome.

Comment: @ZouZou What do you mean by notify? What is that?

Comment: @MagdaleneB. Pay attention to the `break;` instruction. It actually makes your programm correct. Check my edit =)

Comment: I see now, for the Character Stack version. So is the break statement still useful/necessary if I were keep it as a String Stack? Probably not since it's not going through each character one by one right?

Comment: @MagdaleneB. You can keep your String stack too it's correct. But the main idea of checking a word to be a palindrom is to check character by character. Instead of put the character in a String object you could directly but the character itself in the stack, but your version is ok too =)